# CSS file is styling unintended elements

Tags: html, css

Bear with me as I am new to web development and will try to explain my issue properly.

So basically I'm trying to style a certain element on my web page but the issue is that it is also applying that styling to the footer as well, which is not what I want. Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

```
<div id="message" class="bg-dark">
<div class="container-fluid padding">
  <div class="row text-center padding">
      <div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6">
      <h2>CEO's Message</h2>
      <p>content</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-5">
      <img src="images/ceo.jpg" class="img-fluid">
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr class="my-4">
</div>
</div>
```

Now, I've even given the id tag to specifically style this div.

and the footer is as follows:

```
<footer>
  <div class="container-fluid padding">
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="images/irco.png">
        <hr class="light">
        <p>(+92)51 21301</p>
        <p>info@irco</p>
        <p>address</p>
        <p>address</p>
        <p>address</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <hr class="light">
        <h5>Information</h5>
        <hr class="light">
        <p>About Us</p>
        <p>Help Desk</p>
        <p>Support</p>
        <p>Privacy Policy</p>
        <p>Terms & Conditions</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h5>Subscribe to our newsletter</h5>
        <p>Stay updated with all the latest updates.</p>
      </div>

      <div class="col-12">
        <hr class="light">
        <h5>&copy; irco</h5>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

And the styling done in the CSS file:

```
#message h2, p{
    color: white;
    padding-top: 4rem;
}

footer{
    background-color: #3f3f3f;
    color: #d5d5d5;
    padding-top: 2rem;
}
```

Now, even that white color and the 4rem padding is being applied to the footer and the padding is being applied in between the

elements so everything's all stretched out and I can't figure out what I am doing wrong here. What I want is to just simply apply the white color and the padding to the #message portion and leave the footer alone.

Comment: well you have `p` which is going to be every `p` in the document. Did you think `#message h2, p` acted like `#message h2, #message p`

Comment: @Bilal Hakim remove `h2, p` element in your style rule.  Just leave `#message` and see how it goes.

Comment: @epascarello Thank you so much! Yes, I did think that it worked that way, my bad. It's working as expected now with the changes you suggested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is not understanding how selectors work. Your code CSS is basically this

```
#message h2 {
  color: white;
  padding-top: 4rem;
}

p{
  color: white;
  padding-top: 4rem;
}
```

The `#message` only applys to the h2. It does not apply to the `p`

So you need to code it as

```
#message h2, #message p {
  color: white;
  padding-top: 4rem;
}
```

Comment: A safer alternative would be instead of `#id element { ... }` to put `element#id ... ` so that only the elements with that id would be effected and then modify the HTML to read `<h2 id="message"></h2> <p id="message"></p>` etc.

Comment: @JoelTrauger seems like overkill

Comment: It amounts to the same result. Only the `h2` and `p` elements will be modified. Mine is more specific. Yours is more concise.

Comment: Or it will work like how "Cascading Styles" is supposed to work. You way, just use a class and be done instead of using useless ids.

Comment: +1 for referencing what CSS means. If you want your CSS and page design to be editable later without having to add unnecessary ids/classes and `!important` tags, then yes. the specificity of the #message id (or .message class) on each tag opens the CSS up to applying blanket styles to other `<h2>` or `<p>` elements without modifying this section. `p#message {...}` inherits the styles from `p {...}` and so the styles would cascade like they're supposed to. As I said, mine is more specific, yours is less typing in the html. Both would amount to the same thing visually in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the styles to only apply to the #message p tags then you need to list your CSS as:

```
#message h2, #message p {
 color: white;
 padding-top: 4rem;
}
```

You currently have it targeting #message h2 and all p tags